# Developing a dummy command for ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Suppose I want to develop a dummy command or tool for ubuntu, say something like

```
   username@user:~$dummyTool txt
```

which simply displays the list of txt files in the current directory.

Can anyone kindly guide me how do I go about this on the ubuntu platform.

What format I should keep my code in? How do I make it installable? Where should I install it? and I request more information on the similar line.

Once I understand the basic structure I am planning to make something useful.

Comment: For starters, do you know how to accomplish this in Bash?

Comment: No, actually I don't know how to do it in bash either.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an alias in file `.bashrc` (in your home directory), like so:

```
alias txt='ll *.txt'
```

or:

```
alias txt='ls *.txt'
```

(there are other `alias` examples in the file)

The first example above gives a 'long listing'.

Then at the command prompt you can simply input the `txt` alias and press enter. You may have to logout/login again to pickup the change, or do a `. .profile` at the prompt to update the change.

...or, alternatively, simply run the `ll *.txt` or the `ls *.txt` command at any current directory without creating any alias.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. I wish to know how to build something like maven. We have commands like **mvn clean, mvn install** etc. Not something as complex as maven but a simple tool probably. Where is the code written and installed for clean and install with reference to above example. Many thanks in advance!